# appeal a sentence VS appeal the sentence VS appeal against

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases

A.

> a defendant can **appeal a sentence** if it's illegal, unconstitutional,
>   or unreasonably excessive.

B.

> a defendant can **appeal the sentence** if it's illegal, unconstitutional,
>   or unreasonably excessive.

C.

> a defendant can **appeal against a(the) sentence** if it's illegal, unconstitutional, or unreasonably excessive.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A defendant can [**A**] *appeal a sentence* (in general), or [**B**] *appeal the* (particular) *sentence*.

I would not recommend using [**C**] *appeal against a / the sente*nce, as a legal appeal is, by definition, an opposition of a / the sentence. I wouldn't go so far as to say that it's grammatically illegal, only that it's redundant, and hence unnecessary.

Google.com, in its definition of [**appeal**](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=appeal+definition+&oq=appeal+definition+&gs_l=serp.12..0i67l2j0l8.6573.6573.0.14155.1.1.0.0.0.0.151.151.0j1.1.0....0...1c..64.serp..0.1.150.Ia7lQF-HD3Y), does include "*against*" in its sample sentence, "he said he would appeal *against* the conviction", yet I believe that “*against*", in this construction, is unnecessary as it adds no semantic or useful information to the statement.

> **An appeal is a challenge to a previous legal determination**. An appeal is directed towards a legal power higher than the power making the challenged determination. In most states and the federal system, trial court determinations can be appealed in appeals courts, and appeals court decisions can be appealed in a supreme court.
>
> The person pursuing an appeal is called an **appellant**, while the person defending the lower court’s ruling is the **appellee**. See, [Legal Information Institute](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/appeal)

Comment: It seems one might be appealing the _ruling, determination, or decision_ that established the sentence, rather than the _sentence_ itself.

Comment: "An appeal is a challenge to a previous legal determination."

Comment: You can appeal (against) the length of a sentence in many jurisdictions separately to appealing the verdict (note that the English government website uses "appeal against"; maybe this is considered clearer language even if "against" is unnecessary) https://www.gov.uk/appeal-against-crown-court-verdict

Answer (score 0):

From my gut feelings, I would choose version A:

> A defendant can appeal **a** sentence...

The indefinite article stresses the *general reach* of the statement.

As a "stronger "argument here some Google phrase search result: [*]

["a defendant can appeal **a** sentence" - Google Search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22a+defendant+can+appeal+a+sentence%22&gws_rd=cr&ei=58V8VdzqIJPd8AWqrYP4CQ): **10 results**

["a defendant can appeal **the** sentence" - Google Search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22a+defendant+can+appeal+the+sentence%22&gws_rd=cr&ei=EMZ8VdeTGIP98QWbsIKICQ): **3 results**

["a defendant can appeal **against** the sentence" - Google Search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22a+defendant+can+appeal+against+the+sentence%22&gws_rd=cr&ei=b8Z8VfvNB8Ht8gX944PgCQ): **0 results**

I guess this indicates strongly that "a defendant can appeal **a** sentence" is the most common version.

---

[*]: Phrase searches are the golden tool for non-natives in case of rare or very new phrases!)

Answer (score 0):

***Appeal against*** is or was British English and ***appeal*** ***without the preposition*** American English, which now dominates in Britain as well. *Appeal* has two meanings, one of seeking redress in legal English and one of attraction (*The job appeals to me*).

I do not fully agree that the preposition "against" here is in itself redundant or unnecessary. The noun may be followed by a variety of prepositions. *Appeal to, appeal for, appeal of, appeal against*. *Appeal* as a verb is supported by a preposition to show whether it is "appeal to" or "appeal against".

"Against" is dying not because it is redundant as such, but because the meaning is always clear from the context. The word originates in appeler call but nobody says "I am appealed /called" so we are left with the two meanings of attraction and seeking redress.  A google search gave  188 k for *appeal against* and 587k for *appeal*.

Comment: Appeal against is certainly used in the UK by both [UK government](https://www.gov.uk/appeal-against-crown-court-verdict) and [Prison Reform Trust](http://www.prisonreformtrust.org.uk/Portals/0/Documents/PIB-Appealing%20against%20your%20conviction%20or%20sentence.pdf), although the [House of Commons Library](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/how-to-appeal-a-criminal-conviction-or-sentence/) has "appeal a conviction/sentence".

Comment: Please give the link to the Google search. One wonders whether 'These two bowlers will appeal even when the ball is pitching a foot outside leg' and even 'what a silly appeal' have been filtered out.